# Android "Cannot resolve symbol" for setOnCheckedChangeListener and buttonView

Tags: java, android, togglebutton

I'm trying to create a switch which when enabled hides a button called `button` but it returns an error for SetOnCheckedChangeListener and buttonView which says `Cannot resolve symbol`

```
package com.jordthedev.firstapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int count = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }


    public void switchActivity(View v){
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
    }

    ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                toggle.setVisibility(toggle.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                toggle.setVisibility(toggle.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: i think there @Override Annotation is Missing....follow my answer for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have to place ToggleButton in onCreate() method try below code

```
package com.jordthedev.firstapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int count = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    toggle.setVisibility(toggle.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                    toggle.setVisibility(toggle.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public void switchActivity(View v){
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
    }



}
```

Comment: Thanks, it fixed the error but now I'm getting a different error:
Error:(24, 21) error: local variable toggle is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final

Comment: Anything used inside inner class of java needs to be declared final. so place final keyword in front like this
final ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);

Answer (score 1):

> Replace your `OnCheckedChangeListener` Code with this

```
ToggleButton toggle =(ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    toggle.setVisibility(toggle.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                    toggle.setVisibility(toggle.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
```